# Fastlane for React Native project (iOS) - IPA file generation issue

Tags: react-native, fastlane

I'm currently facing an issue and would like if anyone has any idea how to solve it. We are trying to use Fastlane to automate .ipa file generation and in the future send builds to TestFlight and Publish on App Store. Every time I run my lane I get a FirebaseCrashlytics error. It complains that the 'mach-o/utils.h' file was not found. XCode builds just fine.

Here's my Fastfile

```
default_platform(:ios)


platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :createIPA  do
    # build your iOS app
  clean_build_artifacts # Delete the local dSYM files
  clear_derived_data #Delete existing derived data
  xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode 2.app")  # Selects more stable Xcode 13.4.1
  xcversion(version: "13.4.1") # Selects Xcode 13.4.1
  
  gym(
      scheme: ENV['SCHEME'],  #{}"iOSConsumerApp-TH",
      sdk: "iphoneos15.5",
      export_method: "ad-hoc",         #"app-store",   #"ad-hoc",
      export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
      
      include_bitcode: false,
       export_options: {
          uploadBitcode: false,
          uploadSymbols: false,
          compileBitcode: false,
       provisioningProfiles: {
              ENV['BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER'] => ENV['PROVISION_NAME_ADHOC'] #ENV['PROVISION_NAME_APPSTORE']
            },
              "signingStyle": "manual"
            }
  )
  end
end
```

But by the end of the build I get this

```
❌  /Users/tiagoluizbassani/Projects/fabric-integration-mobile-fastlane/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/Crashlytics/Shared/FIRCLSMachO/FIRCLSMachO.m:24:10: 'mach-o/utils.h' file not found

#include <mach-o/utils.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling FIRCLSMachException.c
▸ Compiling FIRCLSLogger.m
▸ Compiling FIRCLSLaunchMarkerModel.m
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/tiagoluizbassani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fabric-fikcxkuzhuymdobpblkynygnanwc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/UAT/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCrashlytics.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FIRCLSMachO.o /Users/tiagoluizbassani/Projects/fabric-integration-mobile-fastlane/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/Crashlytics/Shared/FIRCLSMachO/FIRCLSMachO.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'FirebaseCrashlytics' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
[16:07:05]: Exit status: 65
```

Can anyone help?

Followed online tutorials and was hoping to successfluly gegerate an .ipa file.